# Frequency Arbitrage

Tags: volatility, arbitrage, mean-reversion, statistical-finance

We know that the volatility is lower when the sampling period is longer, for example $\sigma_{7days} < \sigma_{1day}$, Then I came across this strategy that I cannot quite understand how to exploit this:

It says:
If weekly historical vol < daily historical vol:
buy strip of T options, delta hedge daily;
                                             sell strip of T options, delta hedge weekly.

Adding up:

We do not buy nor sell any option;
play intra-week mean reversion until T;

Daily Vol / weekly Vol Arbitrage:
On each leg: always keep $a invested in the index and update every Δt;

Resulting spot strategy: follow each week a mean reverting strategy;

Prove that we should keep each day the following exposure:
$$ a.(\frac{1}{S_{t_{i,j}}} - \frac{1}{S_{t_{i,1}}})$$
where $t_{i,j}$ is the j-th day of the i-th week

It amounts to follow an intra-week mean reversion strategy

Could someone helps to explain a little?

Comment: Bruno Dupire is the author of this strategy.

Comment: yes! but I don't quite understand @Alex C